# Angular ngx-translate causing elements to be repainted

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am relatively new to Angular development and I'm not sure if the following behavior is normal or not. I have a small application that supports 2 languages, `us` and `nl`. For translations I'm using `@ngx-translate` by following the steps [on their github page](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#usage).

I am using the translation directive like bellow

```
<select formControlName="cheese_code" name="cheese_code" id="cheese_code" class="custom-select" required tabindex="4">
<option [translate]="'Select your cheese'" value="" selected></option>
<option *ngFor="let cheese of cheeseList$ | async" [ngValue]="cheese.id">{{cheese.name}}</option>
```

Under my `assets\i18n` folder there are two json files, `en.json` and `nl.json`. `en.json` does **not** contain a translation for `'Select your cheese'`, while `nl.json` does have it.

What I expect is along the lines of what is happening, as in, if I choose English as the application language then I see the text 'Select your choice' in the dropdown (given there is no translation for it, it will use this as default), while if I switch languages, the translated text is displayed.

The weird thing that for `en`, the dropdown constantly gets repainted, every 1s. In Chrome, if I enable the option `Paint flashing`, I can see that element constantly gets repainted when language is set to `en`, but this does not happen if the language is `nl`, so where the translation actually exists, in `nl.json`.

Is this normal? In the case that I will render 100x more elements on the page than now, will this become a performance issue?